# How to fill a form field based on another field in Django template using Ajax+jQuery

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to populate the **unit of measure** field based on a **product** selected by the user using a dropdown. In my products model each product has been assigned a unit of measure and I am trying to autofill the unit field during order creation.

I am using jQuery to pick up the product by and capturing the event `.on('change')`. In my endeavour to complete the scenario, I have tried to use this example code [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html) .

In the example, we are checking if a particular name entered by a user exists or not using Ajax calls sent to the database, which I have been able to replicate. What I am unable to get around to, is picking up the related field value "**unit of measure**" on selection of a "**product**".

What would be the correct way to send Ajax call to the database to pick up associated value of **unit of measure** based on selection of the **product**?

**Edit**

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=300000000000000000)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Prod.Short text')
    default_uom = models.ForeignKey(Unit_of_Measure, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='UoM')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} : {1}'.format(self.product_id, self.description)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

    # ...
    path('ajax/uom/', fill_UoM, name='fill_unit_of_meas'),
    # ...
```

**Note:** Initially I had included the url path in app root, now I have moved it to the project root.

**Edit 2**

**Note :** **views.py** and HTML **template** have been modified and shown below (old code removed to make the reading easier).

**1. Model: "Unit_of_Measure"**

```
class Unit_of_Measure(models.Model):
    uom = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True, help_text='Units of measure')
    uom_desc = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, help_text='Base UoM description')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} ({1})'.format(self.uom, self.uom_desc)
```

### **VIEWS.PY (Modified)**

```
def fill_UoM(request):
    product_id = request.GET.get('product_id', None)
    data = {
        'default_uom': Product.objects.filter(product_id=product_id).values()
        }
    return JsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)     #   (data_serialized, safe=False)
```

### **HTML TEMPLATE (Modified)**

```
function fillUoM() {
// FUNC TO GET UNIT OF MEAS ON MATERIAL SELECTION AND UPDATE THE UoM FIELD
    console.log('**** FUNCTION ENTERED ON MATERIAL SELECTION NAME OF FUNC: ' + 'fillUoM');
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url 'fill_unit_of_meas' %}',
        data: {product_id: matl_sel},       //  "matl_sel": SELECTED PRODUCT ID PASSED >> jQuery ".on('Change')"
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {       //  error
            console.log('The value captured is: ' + data)
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('Data could not be retrieved: ' + data)
        }
    });
};
```

And now I am not getting any errors but no result being returned as well. BTW, out of desperation and to test if the code (**views.py**) is working, I tried to return the value of product id, but of course it is not working.

This is the **console.log**:

> The value captured is: mat_default_uom

**Thanks**

Comment: Show model, view and html page related to the above stated question.

Comment: @AmandeepSinghSawhney Updated my question to include codes.

Comment: @ Can you please add Unit_of_Measure model also ? Then i will finally answer your question.

Comment: @AmandeepSinghSawhney Made some changes to my codes. I am updating those as well as add the Unit_of_Measure model also please.

Comment: @AmandeepSinghSawhney Have added the table UoM and modified to show the current situation. Thanks.

Comment: I have answered. Do let me know if it solved your problem or if it produced any error.

Comment: @user12379095 I was trying to solve this same issue with my code. Would you help me by showing your HTML? Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax function

```
function fillUoM() 
{
    $.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'fill_unit_of_meas' %}',
            data: {"product_id": matl_sel},       
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {console.log('The value captured is: ' + data.default_uom)},
            error: function(data) {console.log('Data could not be retrieved')}
        });
};
```

views.py

```
def fill_UoM(request):
    product_id = request.GET.get('product_id', None)
    data = {'default_uom': Product.objects.get(product_id=int(product_id)).default_uom.uom}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: To use an analogy, it went like a Hot knife thru' Butter!! Many thanks. If I may ask, could you please clarify one thing : if I remove the reference to the FK model "Unit_of_Measure" from `data = {'default_uom': Product.objects.get(product_id=int(product_id)).default_uom.uom}` and instead have `data = {'default_uom': Product.objects.get(product_id=int(product_id)).default_uom}`, I get an ERROR saying "Object of type 'Unit_of_Measure' is not JSON serializable". What is the system telling me here?

Comment: ```Product.objects.get(product_id=int(product_id)``` will give an object of Unit_of_Measure model which you are trying to send in a json response.This doesn't work in django.I would advice you to go through these questions: stackoverflow.com/q/16790375/10585627 and stackoverflow.com/q/21925671/10585627 .

Comment: The solution provided by you has really been of great help. I need a clarification though, if I may. The Ajax solution works perfectly with normal `select` but when used with Django autocomplete light, it does not work. What could be wrong and how do I solve it? If required, I can post a new question.

Comment: You may post a new question. Others will find it helpful if they get stuck at the same problem. I will answer it if i can. Thanks

Comment: Posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59593318/12379095). Thanks.

Comment: With the same arrangement as before, but using `.on('focusout')` I am able to fill the UoM field but I can see a `NaN` error in the console. The `.on('change')` event not having any effect at all.

Comment: Sorry i haven't used Django autocomplete light before. I will have to go through the documentation to help you with this.I am busy with some other tasks. Sorry!

Comment: No problem. I am exploring. In case I find something I will post it. Thanks.

Comment: @AmandeepSinghSawhney Hi, I also going through the same issue, can you show your HTML part? It will be much helpful for me

Comment: @ToufiqurRahman It's been a long time and i do not remember question details. Sorry !